# Find all sentences containing specific words

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string consisting of sentences and want to find all sentences that contain at least one specific keyword, i.e. `keyword1` or `keyword2`:

```py
import re

s = "This is a sentence which contains keyword1. And keyword2 is inside this sentence. "

pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z][^\.!?].*(keyword1)|(keyword2).*[\.!?])\s")
for match in pattern.findall(s):
    print(match)
```

Output:

```
('This is a sentence which contains keyword1', 'keyword1', '')
('keyword2 is inside this sentence. ', '', 'keyword2')
```

Expected Output:

```
('This is a sentence which contains keyword1', 'keyword1', '')
('And keyword2 is inside this sentence. ', '', 'keyword2')
```

As you can see, the second match doesn't contain the whole sentence in the first group. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negated character class to not match `.` `!` and `?` and put the keywords in the same group to prevent the empty string in the result.

Then re.findall returns the capture group values, which is group 1 for the whole match, and group 2, 3 etc.. for one of the keywords.

```
([A-Z][^.!?]*(?:(keyword1)|(keyword2))[^.!?]*[.!?])\s
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `[A-Z][^.!?]*` Match an uppercase char A-Z and optionally any char except one of `.!?`
  - `(?:(keyword1)|(keyword2))` Capture one of the keywords in their own group
  - `[^.!?]*[.!?]` Match any char except one of `.!?` and then match one of `.!?`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s` Match a whitespace char

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zNFfDQ/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JY3kgz).

**Example**

```
import re

s = "This is a sentence which contains keyword1. And keyword2 is inside this sentence. "

pattern = re.compile(r"([A-Z][^.!?]*(?:(keyword1)|(keyword2))[^.!?]*[.!?])\s")
for match in pattern.findall(s):
    print(match)
```

**Output**

```
('This is a sentence which contains keyword1.', 'keyword1', '')
('And keyword2 is inside this sentence.', '', 'keyword2')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need each keyword inside an own group for further preprocessing :/.

Comment: @Ronaldinho In that case you can use `([A-Z][^.!?]*(?:(keyword1)|(keyword2))[^.!?]*[.!?])\s` See https://regex101.com/r/kJoAzn/1

Comment: @Ronaldinho I have updated the example for a separate capture group value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following regular expression:

`[.?!]*\s*(.*(keyword1)[^.?!]*[.?!]|.*(keyword2)[^.?!]*[.?!])`

Code:

```
import re

s = "This is a sentence which contains keyword1. And keyword2 is inside this sentence. "

pattern = re.compile(r"[.?!]*\s*(.*(keyword1)[^.?!]*[.?!]|.*(keyword2)[^.?!]*[.?!])")
for match in pattern.findall(s):
    print(match)
```

Output:

```
('This is a sentence which contains keyword1.', 'keyword1', '')
('And keyword2 is inside this sentence.', '', 'keyword2')
```

Comment: Can you explain your regex? What was the issue with the one from the question?